# TCPの接続終了フェーズでは、なぜFINパケットでなくFIN/ACKパケットを最初に送るのですか？

Tags: tcp

## 背景

[パケットキャプチャの教科書](https://www.sbcr.jp/product/4797390711/) を読んで、TCPについて勉強しています。

TCPの接続終了フェーズでは、FIN/ACKパケットを送ることが分かりました。

```
      TCP A                                                TCP B

  1.  ESTABLISHED                                          ESTABLISHED

  2.  (Close)
      FIN-WAIT-1  --> <SEQ=100><ACK=300><CTL=FIN,ACK>  --> CLOSE-WAIT

  3.  FIN-WAIT-2  <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=ACK>      <-- CLOSE-WAIT

  4.                                                       (Close)
      TIME-WAIT   <-- <SEQ=300><ACK=101><CTL=FIN,ACK>  <-- LAST-ACK

  5.  TIME-WAIT   --> <SEQ=101><ACK=301><CTL=ACK>      --> CLOSED

  6.  (2 MSL)
      CLOSED

                         Normal Close Sequence

                               Figure 13.
```

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#section-3.5 引用

## 質問

なぜFINパケットでなくFIN/ACKパケットを送る必要があるのでしょうか？
TCPの接続フェーズではSYNパケットを送りますが、それと同様にFINパケットのみ送るのが自然だと思いました。

## 参考

https://kawasin73.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/08/31/153809#fn:1

## 回答を受けた上での補足

ACKフラグについて、少し勘違いしていました。
送信側のパケットにもACKフラグを付けることを、理解していませんでした。
[Transmission Control Protocol - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)のACKフラグの説明を見て、理解しました。

> 確認応答番号フィールドが有効であることを示す。最初のSYNパケットを除く以降の全パケットでこのフラグをセットする。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> なぜFINパケットでなくFIN/ACKパケットを送る必要があるのでしょうか？

FIN/ACK送る必要がある, 訳ではなく, たまたま観測したパケットがそういう環境だったのでしょう
別に, FIN => FIN/ACK => ACK でも構わないはず
(FINに対し いきなり RST 送りつける OS もある(今もそうなのか不明))

> TCPの接続フェーズではSYNパケットを送りますが、それと同様にFINパケットのみ送るのが自然だと思いました。

同じ 3ウェイ・ハンドシェイクという意味かもだけど, 状況が異なるので自然ではありません

- フロー制御行ってるので, connection後のパケットでは大抵 ACK付けるはず
  (ACK付けないパケットは, 受信した分を(未だ)受け付けない, ようなもの)
- 片方だけ connection閉じて(送信のみとか受信のみとか), 少しの間維持する場合もある。このとき片側で FIN/ACKのみ使用して, その後もパケット受け付け(あるいは送りつけ)行うことも

Comment: >FIN/ACK送る必要がある, 訳ではなく, たまたま観測したパケットがそういう環境だったのでしょう
sayuriさんの回答にある通り、FIN/ACKで送るのはRFCで決まっているので、たまたま観測したパケットだからではないと考えています。

Comment: >(ACK付けないパケットは, 受信した分を(未だ)受け付けない, ようなもの)
ここの部分で「ACKフラグを付けた方が自然」だと考えるようになりましたので、解決済にします。

Comment: @yuji38kwmt 回答に追記予定だけど, もうしばらくかかりそうです

Answer (score 1):

[TCP/IP プロトコルスタックを自作した方のブログで言及](https://kawasin73.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/08/31/153809)されていました。

[3.9 Event Processing の SEGMENT ARRIVES](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc793#page-72)には

```
    fifth check the ACK field,

      if the ACK bit is off drop the segment and return

～～～

    eighth, check the FIN bit,

      Do not process the FIN if the state is CLOSED, LISTEN or SYN-SENT
      since the SEG.SEQ cannot be validated; drop the segment and
      return.
```

となっていて、`FIN`パケットには`ACK`も含めておかないと、step 8に到達する前のstep 5で破棄されてしまうそうです。

Answer (score 0):

TCPの接続確立の際は、最初にSYNだけというのは理解されている通りです。
そして、その後は最後までACKを付け続けるルールと理解すれば、FINだからといってACKのがあることに違和感はないかと。